# Filter SqlDataReader with Where Clause

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ado.net, sqldatareader

I have the Client as below

```
Id  Name status  
1   A      Y  
2   B      Y  
3   C      Y  
4   D      N
```

My requirement to retrieve the results and filter them, through `SqlDataReader` only.

Here what I'm doing,

I'm executing the select statement from `SqlDataReader`.
Once the results are returned to my `SqlDataReader`, then I'm not able retrieve the results by keeping where clause on `SqlDataReader`.

May I know, how can I read the `SqlDataReader`with condition based?

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, Name , Status FROM Client;",connection);
connection.Open();

SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //Here, I have to to filter the results like
        //Select * from Client where status = 'N'                
    }
}
```

Please suggest??

Comment: May I ask you why a normal SQL WHERE clause is not good here?

Comment: This seems like a _really bad idea_. It forces your clients to do the filtering work, rather than letting the database do it. The database is **good** at this: it has indexes and other features that allow it to filter data efficiently. It's also very slow to pull entire tables to your clients over the network.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, I understand your concern. But, I have to filter from .Net side, as I have to see whole result, before moving next step in business scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reader cannot filter until it reads but you can continue.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    status = rdr.getstring(1);
    if (status != 'N') continue;
    // process 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A normal SQL WHERE clause is the right path for this. It will retrieve only the records required and no more testing with if are necessary to filter out the unwanted rows. Of course, a parameterized query will help a lot with the possibile variance of the filter

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT ID, Name , Status FROM Client
                                      WHERE status = @st;",connection);    
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st", "N");  // Or use a passed string variable
connection.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // Here you have only the records with status = "N"
    }
}
```

Other advantages of this approach are explained in the comment above from Mr Joel Coehoorn.

Comment: Stated question is "My requirement to retrieve the results and filter them, through SqlDataReader only."  This does not address the stated question.  If you feel the question was wrong then the remedy is a comment.

Comment: Perhaps you are right about the "stated question", but that's should not stop anyone to show, with an answer, what should be the correct way to handle the situation. I feel that giving just a comment it is not enough here. It is like to say: "You are doing all wrong...." and then walk away leaving the poster in the dark. On the other side you are right giving a "correct to the stated question" answer also if the answer has more cons than pros. (By the way, can you explain what does it means _filtering with a SqlDataReader_?)